# Azure App registration: "Delegated permission" is disabled

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I created two applications in Azure `App registrations`: `app.client` and `app.server`. I added a role in `app.server` application manifest:

```
...
    "appRoles": [
        {
            "allowedMemberTypes": [
                "User",
                "Application"
            ],
            "description": "some_role",
            "displayName": "some_role",
            "id": "d1c2ade8-98f8-45fd-aa4a-6d06b947c66f",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "lang": null,
            "origin": "Application",
            "value": "some_role"
        }
    ]
...
```

I use both `user` and `application` because I want to use this role with and without signed-in user. But I can't add `some_role` as `Delegated permission` for `app.client`. Only `Application permissions` is active. `Delegated permissions` is disabled. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegated permissions are not defined in appRoles.
They are defined in oauth2Permissions. 
You can also use the Expose an API page to define them.

https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad